# Can't edit command in Zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a custom prompt in Zsh. At the end of it, I colour the last character red or green depending on if the last command succeeded or failed. However, when I do this, I can't go back and edit previous commands.

This is the prompt code:

`%{%F%(?.$fg[green].$fg[red])>%f%}`

An example workflow:

1. I enter a command that wraps onto a new line:

`> printf "%s\n" "This is a very long printf. How long is it? It's so very very long that it wraps onto the next line."`

2. After this runs, I hit up arrow and modify the command by deleting and retyping "is it". Now, the command line shows:

`> printf "%s\n" "This is a very long printf. How long is it It's so very very long that it wraps onto the next line."`

3. This prints out:

`This is a very long printf. How long iis it It's so very very long that it wraps onto the next line.`

I assume that I'm not terminating the color codes somehow so that the prompt is spilling over into the actual commands I'm trying to enter. It only misbehaves when the prompt wraps around to a new line. Can anyone see what's wrong with my prompt?

I've verified that, without this snippet of code, the rest of the prompt is fine and behaves as you'd expect.

Comment: What exactly is inside your `fg` array? Knowing exactly how you are changing colors will let me clean up my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` is confused about how long the prompt actually is. The shell already knows that its own `%F` escape doesn't contribute to the on-screen length of the prompt; you don't need to wrap it in `%{...%}` like you would similarly do in `bash`.

```
PS1="%F%(?.$fg[green].$fg[red])>%f"
```

If `fg` contains actual terminal-specific escape sequences, then you would need `%{...%}`, but you wouldn't use `%F` at all, as this isn't how you use it. So you might actually need something like

```
PS1="%(?.%{$fg[green]%}.%{$fg[red]}%})>%f"
```

But, you don't need a separate array of colors; `zsh` has them built in as well.

```
PS1='%(?.%F{green}.%F{red})>%f '
```

Comment: Thanks! The issues ended up being that I was using `%{...%}`, as you point out.

Comment: I'll remove the array of colours; nice catch!